# Hibernate One-To-One mapping error with reference key was null

Tags: hibernate-mapping, one-to-one

I have 2 class Customer and Passport with 1-1 relationship. 
I want Passport table will store it's owner Id (Customer_Id). 
But after save to database the Customer_Id alway be null, what wrong with my configure.

Customer Class

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Passport passport;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="customer")
    public Passport getPassport() {
        return this.passport;
    }
}
```

Passport Class

```
@Entity
public class Passport {

    private int id;
    private String name;

    private Customer customer;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="customer_fk")
    public Customer getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }
}
```

Unit Test Class

```
public class CustomerTest extends BaseTest {
    @Autowired
    private ICustomerService customerService;

    @Test
    public void saveTest() {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setName("Nguyễn Thành Trung");
        Passport passport = new Passport();
        passport.setName("Trung passport");
        customer.setPassport(passport);
        customerService.save(customer);
    }
}

Hibernate: insert into public.Customer (name) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into public.Passport (customer_fk, name) values (?, ?)
```

And the result in PostgreSQL tables

Customer Table

> |--Id---|--------Name--------|
>   |---1---|-Nguyễn Thành Trung-|

Passport Table

> |--Id---|--------Name--------|----customer_fk---|
>   |---1---|-Nguyễn Thành Trung-|------------------|

You can see the customer_fk is null and that is my broblem.
Sorry about my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your unit test needs

```
passport.setCustomer(customer);
```